# Why I couldn't change Glyphicons back?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

html:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo@(i.tostring)" id="image@(i.ToString)" onclick=diffImage(this)></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function diffImage(span) {
   var icon = document.getElementById(span.id);
     if (icon.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon glyphicon-star")) {
         icon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
         } else {
         icon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star";
    }
 }
```

After one click it can change from star to heart...but after that it couldn'd change back to star.

If I change to

```
if (icon.className("glyphicon glyphicon-star")) {
```

will show

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected
```

Comment: Do you know how to change the code?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name is different the second time through so it won't match the same way.

```
function diffImage(span) {
    var icon = document.getElementById(span.id);
    var className = document.getElementById(span.id).className;
    if (className == "glyphicon glyphicon-star") {
        icon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-heart";
    } else {
        icon.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-star";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also just use `span` directly. No need for `document.getElementById(span.id)`.